# What is the most convenient alternative to store quantity of time elapsed in a database?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, momentjs, intervals, duration

Taking into account that the elapsed time. For example: 1 month, 1 hour and 30 minutes, 45 minutes, 2 weeks, etc., is a concept called duration in the library moment js or a data type interval in Postgres Databases.

Both are abstractions of the same concept with pros and cons for calculations from the backend / frontend.

What would be the best way to store this data:

1. an integer that stores the amount milliseconds, or
2. a field of type `interval` of Postgres.

So that when working with this data the duration is interpreted although possibly in the same or different units of time?

Answer (score 0):

It it usually a good idea to use the data type that is designed for the purpose, in this case `interval`.

The main advantage is that an `interval` like `1 month` or `1 year 1 hour` (which does *not* correspond to a certain number of seconds) will behave as expected if you add it to or subtract it from a timestamp.

Storing an interval as a numeric data type will only work well if you don't need to represent intervals like the above correctly — but the you can also use an `interval` like `36173.034 seconds`, which will work just as well.